# My Jquery dropdown menu is making my jquery slideshow unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I am building a site for a client that requires a dropdown navigational menu and also a slideshow for the front page. The problem is that the dropdown menu is going behind the slideshow.

[See dropdown menu going behind slideshow](http://premsoft.com/index3.php).

I have tried changing the z-index of #slides to -2 which is successful for bringing the menu above the slideshow but then the information on the slideshow is no longer selectable or clickable. (I want the headings in the slideshow to link to other pages).

[See dropdown on top but text becoming unselectable.](http://premsoft.com/index2.php)

On every other page, the menu drops down above the text like it is supposed to AND the text is still selectable, so all I can figure is that there is some sort of problem/conflict with the javascript in the slideshow and the dropdown menu. I am very familiar with html and css, but a total newbie at javascript, so I really don't even know how to go about finding said conflict. Everything I have read goes back to z-index, but doesn't seem to address the selection problem that is occurring. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I am using.

**HTML for the slideshow**

```
<div id="slides">
<div>
    <img src="/images/slide_building.jpg" alt=""/>
    <h1><img src="/images/h1.jpg" alt="" class="header">Current Happenings</h1>
    <h2>October 9, 2013</h2>
        <p>We are launching our new website, making it even easier to find out about our products and services, get technical information, or contact us. Take a look around, and if you have any questions or feedback, please contact us!</p>
</div>  
<div>
    <img src="/images/slide_partners.jpg" alt=""/>
    <h1><a href="/product_admissionEdits.php"><img src="/images/h1.jpg" alt="" class="header">Admission Edit Software</a></h1>
        <p>This product allows the users to take control of an account from first contact with the patient and know immediately how accurate the information in the admission is. Premier's Admission Edit products gives your users a score card of any errors and gives them the ability to fix them while the patient is available and motivated to expedite the process. Premier can customize a library of Hospital specific admission edits designed for your hospital making sure the account is accurate at the time of admission.</p>
</div>   
<div>
    <img src="/images/slide_steth.jpg" alt="http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=hospital+computer&search_group=&lang=en&search_source=search_form#id=140644489&src=3uHB0fCguB0lZT5f9lk8mA-1-13"/>
    <h1><a href="/product_clearingHouse.php"><img src="/images/h1.jpg" alt="" class="header">Premier Clearing House</a></h1>
        <p>Premier&rsquo;s Clearing House and Claims Management is the only Clearing House solution, integrated (not interfaced), with MedSeries4&reg; on the Market today. Together with Premiers vast knowledge of MedSeries4&reg;, Our goal is to help you send each claim out the door as clean as possible to ensure a quick positive response from Payers. Once the claim has been submitted, our Claims Management system provides ways to track the claim with continual status updates received from your payers. Our Remittance product imports each remit and updates Claim Management with the final result. Any issues? Simply look at the Claims Management worklist! This and many more tools, have been developed to help you get paid. Let the power of the system you already have work for YOU!!</p>
</div>  
<div>
    <img src="/images/slide_reception.jpg" alt="http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&search_source=search_form&search_tracking_id=3uHB0fCguB0lZT5f9lk8mA&version=llv1&anyorall=all&safesearch=1&searchterm=receptionist+computer+hospital&search_group=&orient=&search_cat=&searchtermx=&photographer_name=&people_gender=&people_age=&people_ethnicity=&people_number=&commercial_ok=&color=&show_color_wheel=1#id=144113761&src=cN4N1pX8F0uxW6Zcbd_PWA-1-80"/>
    <h1><img src="/images/h1.jpg" alt="" class="header">MS4 Software</h1>
        <p>Premier Software assists MS4 Hospitals by increasing cash flow by improving accuracy, efficiency and reducing revenue loss attributed to revenue denial.</p>
</div> 
<div>
    <img src="/images/slide_keyboard.jpg" alt="http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&search_source=search_form&search_tracking_id=cN4N1pX8F0uxW6Zcbd_PWA&version=llv1&anyorall=all&safesearch=1&searchterm=computer&search_group=&orient=&search_cat=&searchtermx=&photographer_name=&people_gender=&people_age=&people_ethnicity=&people_number=&commercial_ok=&color=&show_color_wheel=1#id=95538487&src=NPI2DkDXSeFoSFVNYRh3FQ-1-8"/>
    <h1><img src="/images/h1.jpg" alt="" class="header">ICD 10</h1>
        <p>Are you ready for ICD-10?  Let us provide you with a readiness assessment, technology Gap analysis and help you be prepared with the following      ICD-10 goals</p>
        <ol>
            <li>Completeness. A unique code for all substantially different procedures.</li>
            <li>Expandability. When new procedures are developed a unique new code can be created.</li>
            <li>Standardized Terminology. Each term should be assigned a specific meaning, with no multiple meaning for the same term.</li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS for the slideshow**

```
#slides img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

h1 img.header{
    margin-right:10px !important;
}

#slides h2 {
margin-top: 0;}

#slides {
  display: none
  width: 1130px;
}

#slides div{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

/*Navigation Buttons*/

#slides .slidesjs-navigation {
  margin-top:5px;
}

a.slidesjs-next,
a.slidesjs-previous,
a.slidesjs-play,
a.slidesjs-stop {
  background-image: url(/images/btns-next-prev.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:block;
  width:12px;
  height:18px;

  text-indent: -9999px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

a.slidesjs-next {
  margin-right:10px;
  background-position: -12px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-next {
  background-position: -12px -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-previous {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-previous {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-play {
  width:15px;
  background-position: -25px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-play {
  background-position: -25px -18px;
}

a.slidesjs-stop {
  width:18px;
  background-position: -41px 0;
}

a:hover.slidesjs-stop {
  background-position: -41px -18px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination {
  margin: 7px 0 0;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
  display: block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 13px;
  background-image: url(/images/pagination.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  float: left;

}

.slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
  background-position: 0 -13px
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -26px
}

#slides a:link,
#slides a:visited {
  color: #333
}

#slides a:hover,
#slides a:active {
  color: #9e2020
}


/*----- End SlidesJS Optional -----*/

/*----- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow-----*/

#slides {
  display: none
}
```

**Jquery file for the slideshow (jquery 1.9.1)**

```
(function(){(function(e,t,n){var r,i,s;s="slidesjs";i={width:940,height:528,start:1,navigation:{active:!0,effect:"slide"},pagination:{active:!0,effect:"slide"},play:{active:!1,effect:"slide",interval:5e3,auto:!1,swap:!0,pauseOnHover:!1,restartDelay:2500},effect:{slide:{speed:500},fade:{speed:300,crossfade:!0}},callback:{loaded:function(){},start:function(){},complete:function(){}}};r=function(){function t(t,n){this.element=t;this.options=e.extend(!0,{},i,n);this._defaults=i;this._name=s;this.init()}return t}();r.prototype.init=function(){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"animating",!1);e.data(this,"total",n.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation",n).length);e.data(this,"current",this.options.start-1);e.data(this,"vendorPrefix",this._getVendorPrefix());if(typeof TouchEvent!="undefined"){e.data(this,"touch",!0);this.options.effect.slide.speed=this.options.effect.slide.speed/2}n.css({overflow:"hidden"});n.slidesContainer=n.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation",n).wrapAll("<div class='slidesjs-container'>",n).parent().css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"});e(".slidesjs-container",n).wrapInner("<div class='slidesjs-control'>",n).children();e(".slidesjs-control",n).css({position:"relative",left:0});e(".slidesjs-control",n).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,width:"100%",display:"none",webkitBackfaceVisibility:"hidden"});e.each(e(".slidesjs-control",n).children(),function(t){var n;n=e(this);return n.attr("slidesjs-index",t)});if(this.data.touch){e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchstart",function(e){return a._touchstart(e)});e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchmove",function(e){return a._touchmove(e)});e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchend",function(e){return a._touchend(e)})}n.fadeIn(0);this.update();this.data.touch&&this._setuptouch();e(".slidesjs-control",n).children(":eq("+this.data.current+")").eq(0).fadeIn(0,function(){return e(this).css({})});if(this.options.navigation.active){o=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Previous",text:"Previous"}).appendTo(n);r=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Next",text:"Next"}).appendTo(n)}e(".slidesjs-next",n).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.next(a.options.navigation.effect)});e(".slidesjs-previous",n).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.previous(a.options.navigation.effect)});if(this.options.play.active){s=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-play slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Play",text:"Play"}).appendTo(n);u=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-stop slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Stop",text:"Stop"}).appendTo(n);s.click(function(e){e.preventDefault();return a.play(!0)});u.click(function(e){e.preventDefault();return a.stop(!0)});this.options.play.swap&&u.css({display:"none"})}if(this.options.pagination.active){i=e("<ul>",{"class":"slidesjs-pagination"}).appendTo(n);e.each(new Array(this.data.total),function(t){var n,r;n=e("<li>",{"class":"slidesjs-pagination-item"}).appendTo(i);r=e("<a>",{href:"#","data-slidesjs-item":t,html:t+1}).appendTo(n);return r.click(function(t){t.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.goto(e(t.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item")*1+1)})})}e(t).bind("resize",function(){return a.update()});this._setActive();this.options.play.auto&&this.play();return this.options.callback.loaded(this.options.start)};r.prototype._setActive=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r=t>-1?t:this.data.current;e(".active",n).removeClass("active");return e(".slidesjs-pagination li:eq("+r+") a",n).addClass("active")};r.prototype.update=function(){var t,n,r;t=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e(".slidesjs-control",t).children(":not(:eq("+this.data.current+"))").css({display:"none",left:0});r=t.width();n=this.options.height/this.options.width*r;this.options.width=r;this.options.height=n;return e(".slidesjs-control, .slidesjs-container",t).css({width:r,height:n})};r.prototype.next=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"direction","next");t===void 0&&(t=this.options.navigation.effect);return t==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()};r.prototype.previous=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"direction","previous");t===void 0&&(t=this.options.navigation.effect);return t==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()};r.prototype.goto=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r===void 0&&(r=this.options.pagination.effect);t>this.data.total?t=this.data.total:t<1&&(t=1);if(typeof t=="number")return r==="fade"?this._fade(t):this._slide(t);if(typeof t=="string"){if(t==="first")return r==="fade"?this._fade(0):this._slide(0);if(t==="last")return r==="fade"?this._fade(this.data.total):this._slide(this.data.total)}};r.prototype._setuptouch=function(){var t,n,r,i;t=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);i=e(".slidesjs-control",t);n=this.data.current+1;r=this.data.current-1;r<0&&(r=this.data.total-1);n>this.data.total-1&&(n=0);i.children(":eq("+n+")").css({display:"block",left:this.options.width});return i.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"block",left:-this.options.width})};r.prototype._touchstart=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r=t.originalEvent.touches[0];this._setuptouch();e.data(this,"touchtimer",Number(new Date));e.data(this,"touchstartx",r.pageX);e.data(this,"touchstarty",r.pageY);return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype._touchend=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);u=t.originalEvent.touches[0];s=e(".slidesjs-control",n);if(s.position().left>this.options.width*.5||s.position().left>this.options.width*.1&&Number(new Date)-this.data.touchtimer<250){e.data(this,"direction","previous");this._slide()}else if(s.position().left<-(this.options.width*.5)||s.position().left<-(this.options.width*.1)&&Number(new Date)-this.data.touchtimer<250){e.data(this,"direction","next");this._slide()}else{i=this.data.vendorPrefix;a=i+"Transform";r=i+"TransitionDuration";o=i+"TransitionTimingFunction";s[0].style[a]="translateX(0px)";s[0].style[r]=this.options.effect.slide.speed*.85+"ms"}s.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",function(){i=f.data.vendorPrefix;a=i+"Transform";r=i+"TransitionDuration";o=i+"TransitionTimingFunction";s[0].style[a]="";s[0].style[r]="";return s[0].style[o]=""});return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype._touchmove=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);s=t.originalEvent.touches[0];r=this.data.vendorPrefix;i=e(".slidesjs-control",n);o=r+"Transform";e.data(this,"scrolling",Math.abs(s.pageX-this.data.touchstartx)<Math.abs(s.pageY-this.data.touchstarty));if(!this.data.animating&&!this.data.scrolling){t.preventDefault();this._setuptouch();i[0].style[o]="translateX("+(s.pageX-this.data.touchstartx)+"px)"}return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype.play=function(t){var n,r,i,s=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.playInterval){if(t){r=this.data.current;this.data.direction="next";this.options.play.effect==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()}e.data(this,"playInterval",setInterval(function(){r=s.data.current;s.data.direction="next";return s.options.play.effect==="fade"?s._fade():s._slide()},this.options.play.interval));i=e(".slidesjs-container",n);if(this.options.play.pauseOnHover){i.unbind();i.bind("mouseenter",function(){return s.stop()});i.bind("mouseleave",function(){return s.options.play.restartDelay?e.data(s,"restartDelay",setTimeout(function(){return s.play(!0)},s.options.play.restartDelay)):s.play()})}e.data(this,"playing",!0);e(".slidesjs-play",n).addClass("slidesjs-playing");if(this.options.play.swap){e(".slidesjs-play",n).hide();return e(".slidesjs-stop",n).show()}}};r.prototype.stop=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);clearInterval(this.data.playInterval);this.options.play.pauseOnHover&&t&&e(".slidesjs-container",n).unbind();e.data(this,"playInterval",null);e.data(this,"playing",!1);e(".slidesjs-play",n).removeClass("slidesjs-playing");if(this.options.play.swap){e(".slidesjs-stop",n).hide();return e(".slidesjs-play",n).show()}};r.prototype._slide=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.animating&&t!==this.data.current+1){e.data(this,"animating",!0);r=this.data.current;if(t>-1){t-=1;c=t>r?1:-1;i=t>r?-this.options.width:this.options.width;o=t}else{c=this.data.direction==="next"?1:-1;i=this.data.direction==="next"?-this.options.width:this.options.width;o=r+c}o===-1&&(o=this.data.total-1);o===this.data.total&&(o=0);this._setActive(o);a=e(".slidesjs-control",n);t>-1&&a.children(":not(:eq("+r+"))").css({display:"none",left:0});a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({display:"block",left:c*this.options.width});this.options.callback.start(r+1);if(this.data.vendorPrefix){u=this.data.vendorPrefix;l=u+"Transform";s=u+"TransitionDuration";f=u+"TransitionTimingFunction";a[0].style[l]="translateX("+i+"px)";a[0].style[s]=this.options.effect.slide.speed+"ms";return a.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",function(){a[0].style[l]="";a[0].style[s]="";a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({left:0});a.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"none",left:0});e.data(h,"current",o);e.data(h,"animating",!1);a.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd");a.children(":not(:eq("+o+"))").css({display:"none",left:0});h.data.touch&&h._setuptouch();return h.options.callback.complete(o+1)})}return a.stop().animate({left:i},this.options.effect.slide.speed,function(){a.css({left:0});a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({left:0});return a.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"none",left:0},e.data(h,"current",o),e.data(h,"animating",!1),h.options.callback.complete(o+1))})}};r.prototype._fade=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.animating&&t!==this.data.current+1){e.data(this,"animating",!0);r=this.data.current;if(t){t-=1;o=t>r?1:-1;i=t}else{o=this.data.direction==="next"?1:-1;i=r+o}i===-1&&(i=this.data.total-1);i===this.data.total&&(i=0);this._setActive(i);s=e(".slidesjs-control",n);s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({display:"none",left:0});this.options.callback.start(r+1);if(this.options.effect.fade.crossfade){s.children(":eq("+this.data.current+")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed);return s.children(":eq("+i+")").stop().fadeIn(this.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({});e.data(u,"animating",!1);e.data(u,"current",i);return u.options.callback.complete(i+1)})}return s.children(":eq("+r+")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){s.children(":eq("+i+")").stop().fadeIn(u.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){return s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({})});e.data(u,"animating",!1);e.data(u,"current",i);return u.options.callback.complete(i+1)})}};r.prototype._getVendorPrefix=function(){var e,t,r,i,s;e=n.body||n.documentElement;r=e.style;i="transition";s=["Moz","Webkit","Khtml","O","ms"];i=i.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+i.substr(1);t=0;while(t<s.length){if(typeof r[s[t]+i]=="string")return s[t];t++}return!1};return e.fn[s]=function(t){return this.each(function(){if(!e.data(this,"plugin_"+s))return e.data(this,"plugin_"+s,new r(this,t))})}})(jQuery,window,document)}).call(this);
```

**Javascript for the slideshow**

```
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 340,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 10000,
      swap: true
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML for the navigation**

```
<div class="example">
<div class="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="/index2.php">HOME</a>
            <?php navPage($navSection,"PRODUCTS","products","#"); ?>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/products.php">View All Products</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_admissionEdits.php">Admission Edit Software</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_medicalNecessity.php">Premier Medical Necessity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_electronicRemittance.php">Electronic Remittance Advice and History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_cashReceipts.php">Cash Receipts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_denialManagement.php">Denial Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_expressCinCout.php">Express Check in Check out</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_clearingHouse.php">Premier Clearing House&mdash;EDI Solutions  837 I &amp; P ; 835</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_arTracking.php">Financial Class AR Tracking</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_insuranceEligibility.php">Insurance Eligibility Verification 270 /271</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/product_superBill.php">Super Bill</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of "subs"-->
            </li><!--end of "products"-->
            <?php navPage($navSection,"SERVICES","services","#"); ?>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/services.php">View All Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_projMgt.php">Project Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_analysisPlanning.php">Project Analysis and Planning</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_re.php">RE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_releaseUp.php">Release Upgrades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_implementation.php">Implementation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_training.php">Training</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_contractProg.php">Contract Programming</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_outsourcing.php">Outsourced Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_conversion.php">Conversion Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/services_afterHours.php">After Hours Support</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of "subs"-->
            </li><!--end of "services"-->
            <?php navPage($navSection,"TECHNICAL","technical","#"); ?>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <!--<li><a href="/technical.php">Technical</a></li>-->
                            <li><a href="/technical_version.php">Current Release Levels</a></li>
                            <!--<li><a href="/technical_news.php">Quarterly News</a></li>-->
                            <!--<li><a href="/technical_updates.php">Quarterly Updates</a></li>-->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of "subs"-->
            </li><!--end of technical-->
            <?php navPage($navSection,"COMPANY","company","#"); ?>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/company.php">About Premier</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/company_management.php">Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/company_clients.php">Client Map</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of "subs"-->
            </li><!--end of technical-->
            <?php navPage($navSection,"CONTACT","contact","/contact.php"); ?>
        </ul><!--end of "nav" list-->

</div><!--end of "menu"-->
</div><!--end of "example"-->
```

**CSS for navigation**

```
#current > a{
    background: #21148A url('/images/navbulletcurrent.png') top left no-repeat;
}

#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-stretch:condensed;
    font-size:large;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}

#nav li {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin-right:0px;
    width:188.33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#810046;

}

#nav li a{
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
}



#nav li a:hover {
    background:#21148A;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}

#nav > li.selected > a {
    background:#21148A;
}

#nav li div div {

    display:none;
    width:188.33px;
    position:absolute;

}

#nav li ul li{
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width:138.33px;
    background:#21148A url('/images/navbullet.jpg') no-repeat 16px 14px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:-40px;
    text-align:left;
}

#nav li ul li:hover a{
    background:#505050;
}

#nav li ul li:hover{
    background:#505050;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style:none;

}

#nav ul li{
    float:none;
    border-top:1px dotted #505050;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:medium;

}
```

**Javascript for the navigation**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

$("#nav > li > a").click(function () { // binding onclick
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
        $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

        if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
            $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
        }
    }
}); 

});
```

Comment: A better understanding of CSS z-index stacks is necessary for this one. I don't have yet the solution, but it also can be related to a webkit bug, as it works correctly on firefox (see picture). Why do you use a floating (float:left) menu ? ![Notice the selected text !](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ZDR.png)

Comment: What extension do you use to see this view?

Comment: It's the firefox's default element inspector (not firebug). Click on its second button on the right side menu, the "cube".

Comment: Thanks. I was still on Firefox 8 on my main machine.